# POST preflight Request get rejected with 403 status code

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios, cors, preflight

I´m trying to make a POST request to my API, but the CORS policy is blocking the request in the preflight.

I already configured my back-end to accept requests from the front-end origin and to allow all the methods (including OPTIONS and POST).

**Here´s my Spring CORS Configuration:**

```
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("https://brazilnews.herokuapp.com", "http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "TRACE", "CONNECT")
                .allowedHeaders("append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
```

**Axios Request:**

```
export const api =
    axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    });

export const auth = async (email, senha) => {

    const body = {
        email: email,
        senha: senha
    }

    const res = await api.post("/auth", body)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });

    return res;

}
```

[Request/Response details:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqETU.png)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE9di.png)

Comment: You need to allow the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I added it like this .allowedHeaders("append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization,Content-Type") but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this line in the SecurityConfigurations

`antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`